# Align an anchor inside a div to right

Tags: html, css

I really don't know how to do this. I tried:

```css
#menu-right div {
    position: fixed;      
    text-align: right;
}
```

But this didn't work.

Perhaps it is because `a` is not text. But how do I do this with text?

Comment: Share your HTML markup, we can't easily suggest without you first telling us in code what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [Looking for something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/ZRz26/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the problem this solution should work.

```css
div#menu-right {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;      
    text-align: right;
}
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUB8z/)

Comment: An explanation: the `position: fixed` made the `div`'s width fit to content, rather than be a standard block element which fits width to parent. The `text-align` is still `right`, but where "right" is has changed to where the `a` ends.

Answer (score 0):

Css text-align property doesn't work on inline element like span, a . To align them you can just wrap them with another element like span. In stylesheet, Then select the wrapping element and simply use display: block; After adding this, the text-align property should work well. Write the code like below.
In html:-

```
<span id="menu-right>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
     <a href="#">3</a>
</span>
<!--in the stylesheet write below code -->
<style>
#menu-right{
    display: block; //or use width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
```